# Wolfram Mathematica Plot error what to do

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot this equation

```
Plot[Tan[\[Alpha] Sqrt[\[Beta]^2 - 1]] == ( 0.2 Sqrt[1 - k^2 \[Beta]^2])/Sqrt[\[Beta]^2 - 1], k = 0.75, {{\[Alpha], 0, 1.4}, {\[Beta], 0, 17}}]
```

but I get this error
"Options expected (instead of {{[Alpha],0,1.4},{[Beta],0,17}}) \
beyond position 2 in Plot"An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContourPlot[
 {Tan[α Sqrt[β^2 - 1]] == (0.2 Sqrt[1 - k^2 β^2])/Sqrt[β^2 - 1], k = 0.75},
 {α, 0, 1.4}, {β, 0, 17}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, 1.5}},
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

For example

```
k = 0.75;
sol = FullSimplify[NSolve[
   Tan[α Sqrt[β^2 - 1]] == (0.2 Sqrt[1 - k^2 β^2])/Sqrt[β^2 - 1], α]];
```

When β is 1.25

```
sol /. β -> 1.25
```

> ```
> {{α -> 0.1233747751953911}}
> ```

Plotting with the solution `sol`

```
expr = sol[[1, 1, 2]];
out = Cases[Table[{expr, β}, {β, 1, 1.5, 0.001}], {_Real, _}];
ListPlot[out, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"α", "β"}, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

[image]